# How can i access application.yml values at entity class level

Tags: spring, yaml

I am working on spring boot application and using application.yml file for configuration and looks like:

```
center:
   setting:
      beforeCancellationLimit:
         min: 0
         max: 50
      maximumBeforeCancellationLimit:
         min: 0
         max: 60
      rangeOfCancellation:
         min: 0
         max: 30
```

I want to access these values into my @Entity level class as mentioned below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CENTER")
@TableGenerator(name = "CENTER_GENERATOR", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Center extends AbstractEntityAuditable<User, Long> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6929077991999088544L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CENTER_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @Value("${center.setting.maximumBeforeCancellationLimit.maxv}")
    private byte tMaximumBeforeCancellationLimitMax;

      -- setter and getter--
}
```

but when i print value of **tMaximumBeforeCancellationLimitMax** in setter method then its value is 0.

Please guide how can i access these values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` for injecting values into fields in **Spring-managed beans** and it can be applied at the field or constructor/method parameter level, but your Entity `class Center` is not a Spring-managed beans.

Comment: how can i convert this Entity class into Spring-managed Beans, please suggest me. I already use @Component annotation on that class, but its not working.

Comment: That is imposible.